# Display default WordPress login/registration form into a modal window

Tags: php, functions, forms

hope someone can help me with this. I need to display the default WordPress login/registration into a modal window. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/) in order to create the modal box and it is just exactly what I need, but I do not know how to display the default WordPress login/registration form in this modal window. Please, can anybody give me an advice? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/‎

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Waldermort, but I was thinking not to use a plugin.